# R selenium webdriver not loading element even after wait and scroll down

Tags: r, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to design a scraper for a page in R using the selenium webdriver package and the part of the page I want to scrape is not loading, no matter how long I wait for it to. It may be to do with javascript which I admittedly know nothing about.

I've tried forcing it to scroll down to load the element (in this case a table) but to no avail.

It loads fine in normal browsers.

It's like the severalth site for which this has happened so I thought I'd pop my stackoverflow cherry and ask the experts.

Sorry I have no reprex as I just don't know where the issue is coming from!

The link to the page is
https://jdih.kemenkeu.go.id/#/home

[an image showing what selenium says it sees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHy9M.png) - yellow highlighted area is where the table should load.

[how it is supposed to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZEAs.png) shown in firefox

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

(18 months later and I can answer my own question!)

The issue was that the page is loading content dynamically using an API request.

When scraping using direct GET requests of a URL to extract the page contents, this initial request alone may not load the desired content.

In this case, I found the exact issue by reloading the page with the developer interface open (F12) with the 'Network' (or similar) tab open.

This then shows all the requests made when the browser loads the page.

One of these will be a request for the desired data - in this case by filtering on XHR requests only, I was able to identify one which loaded content through an internal API.

Right-click the request, open in new tab, and voilà, you have a URL which you can use in the same way you would normally with this scraping method that will provide the page content required.

Sometimes the URL alone may not be enough. You will need the correct request headers sent with the request. These can be seen in the request data as mentioned above in the Developer interface in one's browser. Right-click and select 'Copy headers' or similar to get them.

In this case, i.e. when using R, the `httr` package can be used to send get requests with specific headers thus:

```
headers = c(
  "Host" = "website.com"
  [other headers here]
)

page <- httr::GET(url = "www.website.com/data",
                  httr::add_headers(.headers = headers)) %>%
  httr::content()
```

When you have the page content, it is possible to parse the HTML or whatever else is required as usual.